# How can I obtain a one dimensional finite difference formula for $U_{xx}$ with unevenly spaced nodes?

Tags: finite-difference

I know that if I had evenly spaced points, I can use $U_{xx}\approx \frac{U_{i-1}-2U_{i}+U_{i+1}}{dx^2}$.

But if my gridpoints are unevenly spaced, I assume that I can obtain the finite difference formula in the following way:

$D^-[D^+(U)]$, where $D^-$ and $D^+$ are the backward and forward difference formulas.  If I define $h_i=x_{i}-x_{i-1}$, then I think I would obtain:

$D^-[D^+(U)] = D^-[\frac{U_{i+1}-U_{i}}{h_{i+1}}] = \frac{\frac{U_{i+1}-U_{i}}{h_{i+1}} - \frac{U_{i}-U_{i-1}}{h_{i+1}}}{h_i}=\frac{U_{i-1}-2U_{i}+U_{i+1}}{h_ih_{i+1}}$.

However, I have some doubts about this formula.  Particularly, the term $\frac{U_{i}-U_{i-1}}{h_{i+1}}$ might be wrong.  Any feedback on this would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since the finite difference approximation to the gradient is
$$
  u'(x) \approx \frac{\Delta u}{\Delta x}
$$
it is clear that in your original formula, it needs to be
$$
  u''(x) \approx \frac{\frac{U_{i+1}-U_i}{x_{i+1}-x_{i}}
                       -\frac{U_{i}-U_{i-1}}{x_{i}-x_{i-1}}}
                      {\frac 12 (x_{i+1}+x_i)
                      - \frac 12 (x_{i}+x_{i-1})} 
$$
which in your notation is then equal to
$$
  u''(x) \approx \frac{\frac{U_{i+1}-U_i}{h_{i+1}}
                       -\frac{U_{i}-U_{i-1}}{h_{i}}}
                      {\frac 12 (h_{i+1}+h_i)} 
=
 \frac{(U_{i+1}-U_i)h_i
                       -(U_{i}-U_{i-1}){h_{i+1}}}
                      {\frac 12 (h_{i+1}+h_i)h_ih_{i+1}}. 
$$
Conveniently, and not by accident, this reduces to the well-known formula for uniform mesh sizes.

Comment: That makes a lot more sense than what I was thinking!

Answer (score 7):

[This paper](http://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1988-51-184/S0025-5718-1988-0935077-0/S0025-5718-1988-0935077-0.pdf), Generation of Finite Difference Formulas on Arbitrarily Spaced Grids, by Bengt Fornberg, provides Pseudo-Code for the... well... the title is a bit of a give-away.

If you pack it into a loop, you can create Differentiation matrices of arbitrary degrees over arbitrary point sets. If you really need it, I've got a Matlab implementation thereof that creates said matrices, which I could provide on request.

**Update**

[Alexander](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/users/1089/alexander) has just pointed-out [`fdcoeffF(k,xbar,x)`](http://faculty.washington.edu/rjl/fdmbook/matlab/fdcoeffF.m), an implementation of Fornberg's algorithm which computes the weights of the stencil for the `k`th derivative at a point `xbar` over a set of data at points `x`.

Comment: Here matlab implementation is given (maybe you can add it to your answer): http://faculty.washington.edu/rjl/fdmbook/chapter1.html

Comment: This is a great paper! :)